# Не устанавливается соединения websocket для rails чата

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket

Пробую сделать простой чат на RoR, делаю вот по этому видео

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kJbuZecN1c8

на этапе проверки соединения websocket в консоль выводит следующею ошибку

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/cable' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 500
```

с чем это может быть связано, и какие возможные варианты решения?

ссылка на репо https://github.com/movcode/Rails-WebSocket-Example

Comment: 500 обычно это непойманное исключение, открывайте логи, там должны быть детали.

Comment: логи возвращают ошибку `Started GET "/cable" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-04-06 18:19:44 +0300
  
LoadError (/home/alexandr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/nio4r-2.3.0/lib/nio4r_ext.so: undefined symbol: rb_cFixnum - /home/alexandr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/nio4r-2.3.0/lib/nio4r_ext.so):`

Comment: @D-side Разобрался, спасибо за подсказку, просто установил `gem install nio4r -v '2.3.0'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо просто было установить гем `gem install nio4r -v '2.3.0'`

Comment: Любопытно. А как так вышло, что этот гем **был установлен**, но неверно/не до конца?

Comment: У меня не задолго до этого были небольшие проблемы с sidekiq, cron и whenever они почему-то не хотели вмести работать, решения нашлось довольно странное, установить геми бандла в директорию вендор/кеш, это уже я потом узнал про sidekiq-cron и сделал все нормально, при этом удалил все с вендора/кеш, предполагаю что могли остаться некие взаимосвязи. Думаю как то так